# How to add and delete new row with new values each time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been given a task to make 2 HTML pages, one with form where the user enter his/her contact information and another where the user's information are viewed in a table.

I just need to use these languages only (JavaScript, jquery, HTML, CSS ,bootstrap); no use of PHP/JSP, only client-side language
and no database should be used. Up until now I have done this much.

```js
$(function()
{
   $('#form').validate(
   {
    rules:
    {
 email:
 {required:true,
 email:true
 },
 gender:
    {required:true
 },
 cont:{
 required:true,
 number:true}
 }
   
   })

});
function onsumit(){
localStorage.setItem("input0",1);
var ip=document.getElementById("name");
 localStorage.setItem("input1", ip.value);
var ip2=document.getElementById("email");
 localStorage.setItem("input2", ip2.value);
var ip3=document.getElementById("cont");
 localStorage.setItem("input3", ip3.value);
var ip4=document.getElementById("gender");
 localStorage.setItem("input4", ip4.value);
var ip5=document.getElementById("comment");
 localStorage.setItem("input5", ip5.value);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="divmid text-center" id="divmid" >
<p id="head"></p>
<a> CONTACT FORM</a>
<form class="table-responsive" id="form" name="form" action="next.html" method="get" onsubmit="onsumit()" >
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"required>*<p id="p1"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contcat no:</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" name="cont" id="cont"required>*<p id="p2"></p></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMAIL:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"required>*<p id="p3"></p></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td><select id="gender" name="gender" required>
      <option value="" >SELECT</option>
   <option value="male">MALE</option>
      <option value="female">FEMALE</option>
    </select>*<p id="p4"></p></td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>comments:</td>
    <td> <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" maxlength="100"></textarea>
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label><input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></label>


</form>



</div>
```

now this is the second html page.

```js
function load(){
    var table = document.getElementById("tab2");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;    
    var validate_Noof_columns = (colCount - 1);
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
 for(var i=0; i < colCount; i++) {  
             
            var text = localStorage.getItem("input"+i);
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                if(i == (colCount - 1)) {
    newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type='button' value='X' id='work' onclick='removeLine(this)'/><INPUT type='button' value='&' onclick='removeRow(this)'/>"; break;
                }  else  {
                    newcell.innerHTML = text;
                    
                }
  }
function removeLine(lineItem) {
  var row = lineItem.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
function removeRow(onclickTAG) {
    // Iterate till we find TR tag. 
    while ( (onclickTAG = onclickTAG.parentElement)  && onclickTAG.tagName != 'TR' );
            onclickTAG.parentElement.removeChild(onclickTAG);      
}
}
```

```css
body {
      font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: black;
  }
  p {font-size: 16px;}
  .margin {margin-bottom: 45px;}
  .bg-1 {
      background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .bg-2 {
      background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .bg-3 {
      background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
      color: #555555;
  }
  .bg-4 {
      background-color: #2f2f2f; /* Black Gray */
      color: #fff;
  }
  .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
      padding-bottom: 70px;
  }
  .navbar {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav  li a:hover {
      color: #1abc9c !important;
  }
  
  #divmid {
 margin:20px;
 padding:20px;
 border:3px solid red;
  }
 table{
    text-align:left ;


}

th, td {
    padding: 20px;
 text-align:left;
}
textarea{
 max-height:300px;
 resize:none;
}
#div1{
text-align:center;
 
 
}
#tab2 {
    text-align:left ;
 border:2px solid red;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-bottom:200px;

}
#pick{
 
 padding:100px;
 
 }
```

```html
<style>
table, td,th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="div1">
<span id="div2">CONTACT LIST</span>

<table id="tab2">
  <tr>
    <th>S No.</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
 <th>CONTACT</th>
    <th>EMAIL</th>
 <th>GENDER</th>
    <th>COMMENTS</th>
 <th>EDIT</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
  </body>
```

The problem is I need to create a row in second page each time a user input with the new values in the form, but what in have done, it only creating one row and always updating it with the new values. Though I have used Local storage but still I am stuck here.

Comment: Ok. If I understand correctly, you want a form that will transmit data in the localStorage then display them on the screen in a second page. Is that right? If you worked only in client side, you can do this in only one page.

Comment: yes ,you understood correctly but i have to show it on the second page
and yes i have to show the data of all the users.

Comment: I think that the problem is that on your first page, you setItem on the local storage with new values each time. I suggest that you begin the onsubmit function by doing a localStorage.getItem. So you first get the actual values and them you add the new values and setItem. This way you will not loose the old entries

Comment: but i am getting the values by the "getElementById" and then i am setting the value.

Comment: how will we getItem from local storage if we haven't setItem in localstorage.????

Comment: if u can plz show it????

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line 6 of your code. The parameter `1` passed to the insertRow function instantiates the variable `row` with the first row of your table. This way, every time you use insertCell in the `row` variable it updates the value on this first row. I think switching to `rowCount + 1` will do the job.

```
function load(){
var table = document.getElementById("tab2");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;    
var validate_Noof_columns = (colCount - 1);
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount + 1);
for(var i=0; i < colCount; i++) {  

        var text = localStorage.getItem("input"+i);
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            if(i == (colCount - 1)) {
newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type='button' value='X' id='work' onclick='removeLine(this)'/><INPUT type='button' value='&' onclick='removeRow(this)'/>"; break;
            }  else  {
                newcell.innerHTML = text;

            }
    }
function removeLine(lineItem) {
  var row = lineItem.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
function removeRow(onclickTAG) {
    // Iterate till we find TR tag. 
    while ( (onclickTAG = onclickTAG.parentElement)  && onclickTAG.tagName != 'TR' );
            onclickTAG.parentElement.removeChild(onclickTAG);      
}
}
```

Comment: no ,it's not working coz the row count initially is equal to 1 and this makes the function insert the row at 2 position which is not possible.

Comment: Try to put just rowCount in the insertRow method.

Comment: yes ,i did that but still it's showing only one row with current values.

Comment: I think that the problem might be this that i may not be able to store the previous data that's why i am loosing my second row.

Comment: every time the value is updated on the same variable ,and that is why i might not be able to create another row.

Comment: how i hold the previous data in localStorage and then get a new one????

Comment: Try to use jquery instead. This code `$('#tab2').append('<tr> DATA HERE </tr>');` will include a new row in the table everytime it is called. Just pass the right data in the <tr> section.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code. I think it should be what you are looking for.

Everytime the form is submitted, I first get the value of the local storage and add the new entry as JSON.

On the other page, I get the local storage, transform the value to get an object from the JSON string and use that object to show the informations inside the table.

Hope this help!

First Page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function onsumit() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // Exemple of str : {'d' : [{'name':'Mister A','cont':'1',email':'MisterA@test.com'},{'name':'Mister B','cont':'1','email':'MisterB@test.com'}]}
        var str = localStorage.getItem("contactinformation");
        var contactModel;
        if (str !== '') {
          contactModel = JSON.parse(str); 
        } else {
          contactModel = {
            d : []
          };
        }  
        contactModel.d[contactModel.d.length] = {
          name:$('#name').val(),
          cont:$('#cont').val(),
          email:$('#email').val()
        }
        localStorage.setItem("contactinformation",JSON.stringify(contactModel));
        return true;
      } else {
          // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
        return false;
      }

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divmid text-center" id="divmid" >
    <p id="head"></p>
      <a>CONTACT FORM</a>
      <form id="form" name="form" action="next.html" method="get" onsubmit="return onsumit();">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>NAME:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name">*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Contcat no:</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="10" name="cont" id="cont">*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>EMAIL:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email">*</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    table, td,th{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <span id="div2">CONTACT LIST</span>
      <table id="tab2">
        <tr>
          <th>NAME</th>
            <th>CONTACT</th>
          <th>EMAIL</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          var str = localStorage.getItem("contactinformation");
          var info = JSON.parse(str);
          if (typeof(info.d) !== "undefined") {
            for (var x=0;x<info.d.length;x++) {
              $('#tab2').append('<tr><td>' + info.d[x].name + '</td><td>' + info.d[x].cont + '</td><td>' + info.d[x].email + '</td></tr>');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```